# Trying to read a data.txt file and do calculations

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I am using `Integer.parseInt()` to change the String variables of each line of data.txt to an int data type. The data.txt file looks like this:

```
5
6
3
5
0
```

...and so on. I also have no spaces in the text file so I should be able to parse the string of each line perfectly. I also do not have an extra empty line at the end or start of the text file. This is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

And the code:

```
public static int[][][] readFile() throws IOException{
    int[][][] hero = new int[2][2][9];

    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt")))        {
        String line = br.readLine();
        int num;
        while (line != null) {
            for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
                    for (int k=0;k<9;k++){
                        line = br.readLine();
                        num = Integer.parseInt(line);
                        hero[i][j][k] = num;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return hero;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find that bug very easily, when you get *NullPointerException* always try to print it out in the console before doing something to it, just to make sure. I've just added `System.out.println(line)` before `Integer.parseInt()`, remember to do this and it will make your life much much easier in the future.

Answer (score 2):

`null` is provided at the end of file. You should break out of your loop when detected:

```
line = br.readLine();
if (line == null) break;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting null because there are 5 lines on your data.txt and you are reading new lines 37 times (once before the loop and 36 at the three  loops). As stated by robert you should break out of the loop either using break or setting changing the order your code executes. Also, your first read line is not being assigned to your num variable. Try changing to this:

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt")))        {
    String line = br.readLine();
    int num;
    while (line != null) {
        for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
                for (int k=0;k<9;k++){
                    if(line==null){
                        k=9;
                    }
                    num = Integer.parseInt(line);
                    line = br.readLine();
                    hero[i][j][k] = num;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```